# How can I make a single routing rule that matches "archive", "archive/2013" and "archive/2013/02"?

Tags: cakephp

I know that these three routes can be condensed to a single route where :year and :month are optional parameters, but everything I've tried so far simply redirects me to the index if the exact parameters aren't given. For instance, "www.domain.com/blog/archive/" matches the first rules, but "www.domain.com/blog/archive/2013" was falling through to the index rule until I added another specific rule to match it.

```
Router::connect("/$slug/archive", array(
    'plugin' => 'blog',
    'controller' => 'blog_posts',
    'action' => 'archive'
)
);

Router::connect("/$slug/archive/:year", array(
    'plugin' => 'blog',
    'controller' => 'blog_posts',
    'action' => 'archive'
), 
array('pass' => array('year') )
);


Router::connect("/$slug/archive/:year/:month", array(
    'plugin' => 'blog',
    'controller' => 'blog_posts',
    'action' => 'archive'
), 
array('pass' => array('year', 'month') )
);

Router::connect("/$slug/*", array(
'plugin' => 'blog',
'controller' => 'blog_posts',
'action' => 'index'
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a single routing rule use the following code that matches "archive", "archive/2013" and "archive/2013/02"

```
    Router::connect("/$slug/archive/*", array(
      'plugin' => 'blog',
      'controller' => 'blog_posts',
      'action' => 'archive'
      )
    );
```